# Present perfect Present perfect continuous

Tags: differences

What is the difference between those two sentences:

a) A past activity in a time up to the present

b) An activity which began in the past and continues up to the present

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I always understood it as:

present perfect conitnuous - something started in the past and it lasts until now, e.g. "He has been living in New York for 20 years" (and he still does) or "I've been lying in bed since I ate dinner" (and I am still doing it)

present perfect - something happened in the past it is still true now, e.g. "I have done that" (and it's remains done until now), "I have seen it (already)" (and it will never change that I've already seen it)

present perfect could be compared to past simple, because:
past simple - something happened in the past, but it is not important now, it doesn't affect me currently nor it has influence on the subject I'm talking about, e.g.
"Germans lost the World War II" (just a fact from the past) or "During last holidays I went to Paris" (I WENT as single event/activity opposed to I'VE BEEN as a state)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the use of the perfect means that something which happened in the past is still true now. If I say 'He has sometimes thought hard about the problem'. It doesn't mean that he continues to think hard about the problem. That's where there is a need for the perfect continuous 'He has been thinking about the problem since Friday'.

Comment: and how would the meaning change if the sentence was 'He sometimes thought hard about the problem' (or maybe 'Sometimes he thought hard about the problem')? how would a native English speaker understood it if it was in past simple tense? doesn't it depend on the context?

Comment: Probably not at all. The 'perfect' meaning differs little from that of the 'past'. 'I have sold the house' means essentially the same as 'I sold the house'. Indeed in French, in speech and informal writing, they would use the perfect in both instances, without there being any confusion. Only in formal writing would they use the 'Past Historic', as they call it.  It is simply that in English there are some contexts which admit of the perfect and others of the past. If you get them wrong it just sounds clumsy.

Comment: can you give some example of clumsy usage of past simple and present perfect on similar sentences? :) I admit that these difference was always not exactly clear for me and my teachers of English only gave me some "mechanical" rules such as - if the sentence says "LAST year I ..." then we use simple past, and when there is "RECENTLY I ..." then it has to be present perfect, but these are in fact a bit clumsy, because you simple don't have add the "time part", another rule said that "if you tell about something which affects me currently, then it's present perfect" but this is also not obvious

Comment: 'I have washed the dishes' confirms that the job has been done. It might be said in response to someone asking 'Have the dishes been washed?'.  On the other hand if someone asks 'What did you do immediately after dinner', you might say 'I washed the dishes'. But I think this is probably a subject for which you need the English language Learners site. I am supposing that in Polish, like in French and other some other languages, you do not distinguish between past and perfect?

Comment: @Kamil: there are lots of cases where either past simple or present perfect can be used, without much change in the meaning. For an example where there is a difference: if you're asked *"Are you hungry?",* the answer should be *"I've eaten"* rather than *"I ate"*. But it would be *"I ate an hour ago"* rather than *"I've eaten an hour ago"*, because there's a definite time mentioned.

Comment: I don't know French, but yes - in Polish we have just "past" and "present" tense
but anyway, the example you gave about the dishes - it somehow matches what I've written eariler, first - it depends on the context and "what questions does it answer", but when you say "I have washed the dishes" you mean that the dishes are actually clean right now, and by saying "I washed the dishes" you just state the fact that you did that after the dinner, you were asked about what were you doing in particular moment in the past and you answered that and it has no impact on present, am I wrong? :)

Comment: @Peter, yes I know that in many cases these tenses can be both used, but I'd want to know when they can't. I know that I'd say "I've eaten" and "I ate 2 hours ago"... but why do I know that? :)

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk Yes, you seem to be on the right track. There must be some stuff in a grammar book on this. But if you ask a question such as 'When do you use the perfect and when do you use the past?' I will give a list of examples of each in the form of questions and answers.